extract month and year from a Date column of a dataframe that contains different format of dates
I have a dataframe where the Date column contains dates of different formats.
That is, when I import the excel into R, I get
df$Date
  [1] "35826"       "35854"       "35885"       "35915"       "35946"       "35976"       "36007"      
  [8] "36038"       "36068"       "36099"       "36129"       "36160"       "36191"       "36219"      
 [15] "36250"       "36280"       "36311"       "36341"       "36372"       "36403"       "36433"      
 [22] "36464"       "36494"       "36525"       "36556"       "36585"       "36616"       "36646"      
 [29] "36677"       "36707"       "36738"       "36769"       "36799"       "36830"       "36860"      
 [36] "36891"       "36922"       "36950"       "36981"       "37011"       "37042"       "37072"      
 [43] "37103"       "37134"       "37164"       "37195"       "37225"       "37256"       "37287"      
 [50] "37315"       "37346"       "37376"       "37407"       "37437"       "37468"       "37499"      
 [57] "37529"       "37560"       "37590"       "37621"       "37652"       "37680"       "37711"      
 [64] "37741"       "37772"       "37802"       "37833"       "37864"       "37894"       "37925"      
 [71] "37955"       "37986"       "38017"       "38046"       "38077"       "38107"       "38138"      
 [78] "38168"       "38199"       "38230"       "38260"       "38291"       "38321"       "38352"      
 [85] "38383"       "38411"       "38442"       "38472"       "38503"       "38533"       "38564"      
 [92] "38595"       "38625"       "38656"       "38686"       "38717"       "38748"       "38776"      
 [99] "38807"       "38837"       "38868"       "38898"       "38929"       "38960"       "38990"      
[106] "39021"       "39051"       "39082"       "39113"       "39141"       "39172"       "39202"      
[113] "39233"       "39263"       "39294"       "39325"       "39355"       "39386"       "39416"      
[120] "39447"       "39478"       "39507"       "39538"       "39568"       "39599"       "39629"      
[127] "39660"       "39691"       "39721"       "39752"       "39782"       "39813"       "39844"      
[134] "39872"       "39903"       "39933"       "39964"       "39994"       "40025"       "40056"      
[141] "40086"       "40117"       "40147"       "40178"       "40209"       "40237"       "40268"      
[148] "40298"       "40329"       "40359"       "40390"       "40421"       "40451"       "40482"      
[155] "40512"       "40543"       "40574"       "40602"       "40633"       "40663"       "40694"      
[162] "40724"       "40755"       "40786"       "40816"       "40847"       "40877"       "40908"      
[169] "40939"       "40968"       "40999"       "41029"       "41060"       "41090"       "41121"      
[176] "41152"       "41182"       "41213"       "41243"       "41274"       "41305"       "41333"      
[183] "41364"       "41394"       "41425"       "41455"       "41486"       "41517"       "41547"      
[190] "41578"       "41608"       "41639"       "41670"       "41698"       "41729"       "41759"      
[197] "41790"       "41820"       "41851"       "41882"       "41912"       "41943"       "41973"      
[204] "42004"       "42035"       "42063"       "42094"       "42124"       "42155"       "42185"      
[211] "42216"       "42247"       "42277"       "42308"       "42338"       "42369"       "42400"      
[218] "42429"       "42460"       "42490"       "42521"       "42551"       "42582"       "42613"      
[225] "42643"       "42674"       "42704"       "42735"       "42766"       "42794"       "42825"      
[232] "42855"       "42886"       "42916"       "42947"       "42978"       "43008"       "43039"      
[239] "43069"       "43100"       "43131"       "43159"       "43190"       "43220"       "43251"      
[246] "43281"       "43312"       "43343"       "43373"       "43404"       "43434"       "43465"      
[253] "43496"       "43524"       "43555"       "43585"       "43616"       "43646"       "43677"      
[260] "43708"       "30-Sep-2019" "31-Oct-2019" "30-Nov-2019" "31-Dec-2019" "31-Jan-2020" "29-Feb-2020"
[267] "31-Mar-2020" "30-Apr-2020" "31-May-2020" "30-Jun-2020" "31-Jul-2020" "31-Aug-2020" "30-Sep-2020"
[274] "31-Oct-2020" "30-Nov-2020" "31-Dec-2020" "31-Jan-2021" "28-Feb-2021" "44286"       "30-Apr-2021"
[281] "31-May-2021" "30-Jun-2021" "31-Jul-2021" "31-Aug-2021" "30-Sep-2021" "31-Oct-2021" "30-Nov-2021"
[288] "31-Dec-2021" "31-Jan-2022" "28-Feb-2022" "31-Mar-2022" "30-Apr-2022" "31-May-2022" "30-Jun-2022"
[295] "31-Jul-2022" "31-Aug-2022" "30-Sep-2022" "31-Oct-2022" "30-Nov-2022" "31-Dec-2022" "31-Jan-2023"
[302] "28-Feb-2023" "31-Mar-2023" "30-Apr-2023" "31-May-2023" "30-Jun-2023" "31-Jul-2023" "31-Aug-2023"
[309] "30-Sep-2023" "31-Oct-2023" "30-Nov-2023" "31-Dec-2023"

I want to convert this Date column to a new Data column that will contain only the years and the months in this format "3-1998", etc.
I saw from previous threads some potential solutions, for example
format(as.Date(df$Date), "%m/%Y")

but with no success.
Could you help me with that?

One way could be to convert each value in multiple ways and keep the first valid one:
df <- data.frame(Date = c(35826, 43524, "31-Mar-2020", "30-Apr-2020"))
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(Date2 = coalesce(
           lubridate::dmy(Date),
           janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(Date))),
         Date3 = format(Date2, "%m/%Y")) # EDIT

Result
         Date      Date2   Date3
1       35826 1998-01-31 01/1998
2       43524 2019-02-28 02/2019
3 31-Mar-2020 2020-03-31 03/2020
4 30-Apr-2020 2020-04-30 04/2020


Thank you. I get this error
Warning message:
There were 2 warnings in mutate().
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: Date2 = coalesce(lubridate::dmy(Date),   janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(Date))).
Caused by warning:
!  261 failed to parse.
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning.

You should expect warnings (but not an error), because the two functions each expect input of different types, so will fail to parse on the other data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846536/what-is-the-difference-between-warnings-and-messages The coalesce keeps the first non-NA output for each element. Is the output as expected?

I first tried the example code you provided but it did not  work. I still get the  same output as in your df. I also implented your code in my data with the same results.

I edited to clarify the two steps I'd take: 1) convert the disparate date formats to one that is in R's Date format. 2) make a string variable showing mm/YYYY.

It worked! Many many thanks!

Consider a base R solution given Excel integer dates are days since '1899-12-30' (notably not last day of year, '31')
df$Date <- ifelse(
    nchar(df$Date) == 5,
    as.Date(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", df$Date)), origin="1899-12-30"),
    as.Date(df$Date, format="%d-%b-%Y")
) |> `class<-`("Date")

df$Date_MY <- format(df$Date, format="%m/%Y") 

